# loading autokeras model with temporary saved binaries

Tags: keras, auto-keras

As you can see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229283/autokeras-exported-model-performs-not-as-expected), there is a problem with saving and loading autokeras models (please refer to the provided link for more details). I noticed that there are some binaries in the autokeras temporary folder (e.g. /tmp/autokeras_ECWBT7) which contains some binaries:

graph (1.graph, 2.graph, ...)

best_model.txt

classifier

module

temp_model

I could not find any documentation to see how can I use this to load the trained model (if there is any).

I will appreciate if you help me in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Autokeras really has a lack of documentation.
I've found some ways how trained model may be used further (for autokeras version 0.3.7) in case of ImageClassifier:

1. if you are using `autokeras.image.image_supervised.ImageClassifier` and want to continue searching models by using `fit`, or restart `final_fit` for the best model in your *graph_directory*, you can use this:

`clf = ImageClassifier(verbose=True, augment=False, path='./path/to/graph/directory', resume=True)`

2. now you are able to continue net architecture search or export your best model. If you want to export your best model `ImageClassifier` and use it for prediction, you may use:
   `clf.export_autokeras_model('your_model.pkl')`
3. and later you can load it that way:

`from autokeras.utils import pickle_from_file`

`model = pickle_from_file('your_model.pkl')`

and after that you are able to make predictions by:
`y_predict = model.predict(x_test)`

It is suitable solution, if you want work exactly with Autokeras ImageClassifier model later (not convert it into something else).

Comment: Thank you @SmartWaddles, yes I know that, I wanted it like keras model to use it and convert it to other formats as well. other than that, assuming autokeras gives the best model, I want to train it myself with keras for example which is not possible for this format.

Comment: @Ali, oh i see, in case of conversion to Keras, in version 0.3.7 you can use `ImageClassifier.export_keras_model('model.h5')`, but it has the same problem with 'manually compilation', as described in your linked post. However, you may try to compile it by using [link](https://keras.io/models/model/#compile). But there are a lot parameters to pass, and I have exactly the same problem - to pass them all in a right way. For loss `autokeras.nn.loss_function.classification_loss` may be used, but I don't know what with others.